# iReport falta caracter especial ao exportar PDF

Tags: java, jasper-reports, relatório, pdf, jasper

Estou usando o iReport 3.7.4 para gerar os relatórios.
Em um dos relatórios, eu preciso usar uma seta, para indicar um passo a passo.
Então eu achei o código da seta no HTMl Entities ➜ **&# 10140;**, e no campo no iReport, dexei o **Markup** como HTML.
Quando eu exporto o relatório para Word, tudo funciona normal, e as setas do HTML Entities aparecem.

Porem quando eu coloco para exportar para PDF, as setas ( ➜ ) do HTML Entities que indicam o passo a passo desaparecem do relatório.

Alguem tem alguma ideia de como posso solucionar isso ?

➜ =   **&#10140**

Comment: Isso acontece porque a fonte padrão para geração de PDF's (no linux é Helvetica) não aceita esse caracter. Veja neste link as fontes suportadas: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/279C/fontsupport.htm

Comment: Realmente funcionou quando alterei a fonte. Muito obrigado !

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo a dica do Gustavo Fragoso, alterei a fonte para Dejavu Sans, e funcionou:

```
<font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="11" isBold="false" pdfFontName="" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
```

Comment: Eu fiz testes ontem com isso e na hora de gerar o código java o pdf voltou a ser gerado sem o caracter, por isso não respondi. Isso acontece ai também?

Comment: Quando alterei para a fonte DejaVu Sans, o caracter especial apareceu quando gerei o PDF.

Comment: No iReport, fui em Ferramentas -> Opções -> Fonts e vi as que tinha instaladas lá, e as que tinham no site que você passou. E as duas são Dejavu Sans e Dejavu Sans Mono. Testei aqui com essas 2 fonts e funcionou.